# Couldn't get notification using PHP as Backend

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a newbie in Android, I have created a program which will send notification using firebase without using firebase console.I have used php as backend what happeing is I'm getting notification only when send through firebase console, but when I send it through wamp server I can't.though I'm getting success:1.here I'm sharing my code and output as well.

**Index.php**

```
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    require_once __DIR__ . '/firebase.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/push.php';

    $firebase = new Firebase();
    $push = new Push();

    // optional payload
    $payload = array();
    $payload['title'] = 'Notification!';
    $payload['message'] = 'New PickupListed';

    // notification title
    $title = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '';

    // notification message
    $message = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : '';

    // push type - single user / topic
    $push_type = isset($_GET['push_type']) ? $_GET['push_type'] : '';

    // whether to include to image or not
    $include_image = isset($_GET['include_image']) ? TRUE : FALSE;


    $push->setTitle($title);
    $push->setMessage($message);

   if ($include_image) {
        $push->setImage('http://api.androidhive.info/images/minion.jpg');
    } else {
        $push->setImage('');
    }  

  $push->setIsBackground(FALSE);
   $push->setPayload($payload);

    $json = '';
    $response = '';

    if ($push_type == 'topic') {
        $json = $push->getPush();
        $response = $firebase->sendToTopic('global', $json);
    } else if ($push_type == 'individual') {
        $json = $push->getPush();
        $regId = isset($_GET['regId']) ? $_GET['regId'] : '';
        $response = $firebase->send($regId, $json);
    }
```

**MessagingService.java**

```
private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 1=======" );

    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

   if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 2=======" );
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 3=======" );
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void handleNotification(String message) {
    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 4=======" );

    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

        Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message",message);
        intent.putExtra("imageUrl",imageUrl);
        intent.putExtra("time_stamp",timeStamp);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri notificationSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION !!")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager=
                ( NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0,notifiBuilder.build());


        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);




    }
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 4=======" );
    Log.e(TAG, "push json: " + json.toString());


    try {
        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");

        String title = data.getString("title");
        String message = data.getString("message");
       boolean isBackground = data.getBoolean("is_background");
        String imageUrl = data.getString("image");
       String timestamp = data.getString("timestamp");
    JSONObject payload = data.getJSONObject("payload");

        Log.e(TAG, "title: " + title);
        Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
       Log.e(TAG, "isBackground: " + isBackground);
       Log.e(TAG, "payload: " + payload.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "imageUrl: " + imageUrl);
        Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);


        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message

            Intent intent= new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



            Uri notificationSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("NOTIFICATION data message!!")
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_accept,"ACCEPT",pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_decline,"DECLINE",pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(notificationSound)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) ;

            NotificationManager notificationManager=
                    ( NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0,notifiBuilder.build());


            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);

            // play notification sound
           NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();
        } else {

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("message", message);

            // check for image attachment
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {
                showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, resultIntent);
            } else {

                showNotificationMessageWithBigImage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, resultIntent, imageUrl);
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Json Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}



private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {
    Log.e(TAG, "===========================messaging 5=======" );
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);
}
```

[Ravi tamada tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

**But i'm getting this as Output: still not getting notification**

```
Request:
{"data":{"title":"hey all","is_background":false,"message":"demo","image":"","timestamp":"2017-07-27 12:22:41"}}


Response:
"{\"multicast_id\":8934845196536440484,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1501158164597153%293f606ef9fd7ecd\"}]}"
```

Comment: I can't see the target in your sample payload. Are you sending this to a single device or a topic? If to a topic, are you positive that the device is subscribed to that topic?

Comment: @AL.  sending to a single device and can't create where it should be the target

Answer (score 0):

1) Try putting a parameter for priority.

```js
// optional payload
$payload = array();
$payload['title'] = 'Notification!';
$payload['message'] = 'New PickupListed';
$payload['priority'] = 'High';
```

Please don't use it loosely though, in case it works. You can also make a function to define priority in your script for messages that needs immediate delivery (high) as against to "it can wait to process the data when the app comes to foreground" (normal).

2) You are building a Data message. The handling of background processes has changed on Android. You need to complete handling data within 10 seconds of receiving the message or it may not execute.

See [official sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L65) for more.
Now in your handleDataMessage, it might not be long running process but it may still take more than 10 seconds to process. Best thing is to do profiling and see if you need to schedule something or handle data in a more optimized way.

Best Practice:
- Data messaging should only be used for passing on some data to the client that is crucial to be sent to update the app data, reset alarms/timers etc.
- High priority should not be used for each request if your volume / frequency is higher because high priority wakes up a sleeping device to deliver the message which can cause lot of battery consumption. Your users may feel that the app is consuming too much resources and might uninstall or disable notifications.

PS: This post is not meant as a definite answer but mere suggestions and there's a chance your problem might not be resolved by them too.